# How to extract the last forward slash(/) from a concatenated text

Tags: regex, excel, excel-formula, textjoin, vba

I have a column in excel that contains a concatenated string demarcated by ";" e.g

> `SM/123456789/1;PM/123456789/21;AM/123456789/1;GM/123456789/81;QM/123456789/1`

and I want to return the values of the second forward slashes e.g

> `1;21;1;81;1`

NB: I am to extract the last "/" for just one input `SM/123456789/199` using

```
IF(ISERROR(FIND("/",B19)),"",RIGHT(B19,LEN(B19)-FIND("/",B19,FIND("/",B19)+1)))
```

This will extract `199` or 1 in the case of `SM/123456789/1`. How do I achieve this? are there any opportunities for Array formulas here?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that @pnuts

Comment: vba Split rwice in a loop or a global regex; either in a udf.

Comment: This will require one of three: Helper columns, vba, or TEXTJOIN() (which is only available with a subscription to Office 365 Excel).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a subscription to Office 365 Excel use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","/"),"/",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";",""))+1))*3-1)*999,999)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly the Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

If you do not have a subscription to Office 365 Excel You can put this code in a module attached to the workbook and use the formula as described above.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UDF with regex that can optionally replace the delimiter.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0    '<~~this is the default but I've included it because it has to be 0

Function mySplitString(str As String, _
                        Optional delim As String = ";")
    Dim n As Long, nums() As Variant
    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; beneficial when filling a long column with this UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If

    mySplitString = vbNullString

    'make sure the str terminated in a semi-colon
    str = str & Chr(59)

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "\d{1,3}[\;]{1}"
        If .Test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            'resize the nums array to accept the matches
            ReDim nums(cmat.Count - 1)
            'populate the nums array with the matches
            For n = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
                nums(n) = cmat.Item(n)
            Next n
            'convert the nums array to a delimited string
            If delim <> Chr(59) Then
                mySplitString = Replace(Join(nums, delim), Chr(59), vbNullString)
            Else
                mySplitString = Join(nums, vbNullString)
                mySplitString = Left(mySplitString, Len(mySplitString) - 1)
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Used in B2:B3 as,

```
=mySplitString(A2, ",")
=mySplitString(A3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have `TEXTJOIN` function you can try the below, but this approach needs helper columns,

[image]

Formula on cell `B1`,

`=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,";",REPT(" ",999)),(COLUMN(A1)-1)*999+1,999)),"/",REPT(" ",999)),999))`

You have to drag it right till `column F (5 columns)` as the input string contains 5 text stings delimited by `;`. Finally add a formula to `column G` to concatenate all the strings delimited by `;`,

`=B1&";"&C1&";"&D1&";"&E1&";"&F1`